# jQuery.ajax fail handler not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

According to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **Deprecation Notice:** The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

But when I use the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Page("Create", "History")',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'name': value },
    done: function (response) {
        alert('done' + response);
    },
    fail: function (response) {
        alert('fail' + response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('error' + response);
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert('success' + response);
    },
});
```

If my Razor Pages handler throws an exception, the *error* response is shown. (And nothing is shown if I delete the *error* handler.)

I don't mind using `fail` if it's preferred. But if it's not going to be called on errors it won't do much good.

**UPDATE**: I can also see that the *done* handler also doesn't get called unless I change it to *success*.

**UPDATE**: It looks like I'm using jQuery 3.3.1.

Comment: just use the `$.ajax(...).then(() => { /* all good */}).catch(() => { /* error */ })` as they both work normally ...

Comment: @balexandre: I tried just using the `then: function ()...` and `catch: function()`, but neither of those get called. Isn't that functionally the same as what you have?

Comment: doing some tests on jQuery page it's just copy/paste their example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just by using [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it's been a while I don't use jQuery, I try the most to avoid it, there are so much better tools these days

```js
jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'name': 123 }
}).promise();

jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR2 ) { console.log('TEST 1: done', textStatus) });
jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR2, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log('TEST 1: fail', textStatus) });
jqXHR.always(function( data, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log('TEST 1: always', textStatus) });
jqXHR.then(
  function( data, textStatus, jqXHR2 ) { console.log('TEST 1: then1', textStatus) }, 
  function( jqXHR2, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log('TEST 1: then2', textStatus) }
);

// or you can write


$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 'name': 123 }
})
.done(function(data, textStatus) {
  console.log( "TEST 2: success", textStatus );
})
.fail(function(data, textStatus) {
  console.log( "TEST 2: error", textStatus );
})
.always(function(data, textStatus) {
  console.log( "TEST 2: complete", textStatus );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. I have no idea what the difference is between `done: function () { }` and `.done(function () {})`, but the former appears to be unreliable for some strange reason.

Comment: As long as it works... that’s the important part 